# Playing sound through headjack and recording sound on USB

Tags: audio

I have a USB mic plugged in and a aux cord speaker plugged in to my Raspberry Pi.

But when I try to set up each one it make the other one does not work, for example.

```
sudo nano ~/.asoundrc
```

then I type this in:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
}
```

and my mic will work. But then my headphone jack doesn't so I use `sudo raspi-config` and set my Audio to "Force 3.55m jack" and now my mic doesn't work.